# Reading csv column in python returns error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a problem concerning a certain csv column.
When trying to read this column as following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('master.csv')
print(data['gdp_for_year ($)'])
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\work\venv\Suicide rate prediction based on GDB\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'gdp_for_year ($)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/work/PycharmProjects/Suicide rate prediction based on GDB/project.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(data['gdp_for_year ($)'])
  File "C:\Users\work\venv\Suicide rate prediction based on GDB\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\work\venv\Suicide rate prediction based on GDB\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'gdp_for_year ($)'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong? 
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: `gdp_for_year ($)` is not a valid column name. Can you post the header in `master.csv`?

Comment: check `print(data.columns)` or `print(data.dtypes)` to see what columns you have. Maybe you will have to add some options in `read_csv()` - ie. maybe file doesn't use comma separator but somthing different - ie. semicolon `sep=";"`

Comment: It's works for me. Please post at least the first 2 lines of your `master.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Well, `"gdp_for_year ($)"` is not a valid column name

Comment: yes. I tried to show columns and can't find the column name although it is present in the csv file!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
data.columns
```

To see what the column names are to make sure you have the matching column name

Comment: I tried to show columns and can't find this column name although it is present in the csv file!